Best way to offer a choice between 33+ items
I have a website for a card game that has "seasons". There are four of these seasons per year. When there were only a few seasons a dropdown sufficed to allow you to time travel between seasons. But now there are 32 seasons (plus "all time") it's getting unwieldy. The seasons are numbered but you're not exaclty choosing a numeric value, especially because you can choose to look at the "all time" stats as well as those for one particular season.
By far the most common use case is to look at the current season - "what's happening now". It is also fairly common to look at "All Time" to see "is this card any good, is this player any good, is this particular strategy any good" in a more general sense. Then there are a long tail of reasons to look at particular past seasons including curiosity, nostalgia, looking at how a particular card was used "last time" and so on. In the case of cards, they may or may not have been legal to play in a particular season (in the example below Brainstorm was legal only in Seasons 18 and 22, although many have been legal most or all of the 33 seasons so far). In the case of a player they may or may not have played in a particular season. Very few players have played all 33 seasons but many have played a lot.

What would be the best way of presenting this choice to people?
Edit to add: thanks to the awesome advice from @ToddBFisher I went with a grid like this –

It's definitely not perfect but it's a big improvement. Further hints gratefully accepted!

Can you give more context? Based on what criteria and why do people select a season for example?

I added a paragraph about when and why you might time travel back to a particular season.

fwiw as I read through your 2nd paragraph it made me want to see a line chart/graph of the stats related to that specific card over time, with one axis being the season number.

Yes, there are a few graphs on the site but now we have so much history we definitely need to add more!

It would be helpful to think through how your users would expect to find the information they are looking for. On top of that, condensing the options in some way would make it feel less unwieldy.
One potential solution, instead of listing them all vertically, put them in some sort of a grid, such as:

This could either be part of the main navigation or as a pop-up when pressing a "show filter options" type of button.
Other possibilities:

Have the user select the year, then show the seasons that fit into that year. Could be via expanding an accordion.
Paginating the results, such as only show 10 results, with an option for the next / previous page grouping
If users typically do not jump around too much, but instead usually go to the next or previous season, you could simply have next/prev buttons.
Additionally you could have the season numbers inbetween the next/prev buttons, something like <prev 1 2 3 4 5 ... next>
As Danielillo suggested, looking around at similar apps to draw further inspiration could also spark some more ideas.


This was awesome advice, thank you. I edited my question to include a screenshot of a grid version. What do you think?

It can help to get ideas from di.fm where there are more than a hundred playlists to choose from  arranged in a carousel:


I dunno. That doesn't look very intuitive, it's just a randomly-organized set of tags to scroll through, no?

Since there is a wide range of use cases possible, and the main problem is there are too many seasons to choose from, a simple filter would be the way to go. Starting with shortcuts for the current season and for "all time". These can be links or buttons.
For the seasons, group them by year in a dropdown:
Seasons by year:
[2023: 29 - 32]
[2022: 28 - 25]
etc.

Once the year is selected, show the seasons. Since there are a maximum of four, these can be radio buttons to make selection faster.
Season:
( ) 29
( ) 30
( ) 31
( ) 32

